# How can I call a Javascript variable on PHP(HTML)

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

So what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">
var i = 1;
function changeIt()
{

    my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"Titulo: <input type='text' name='mytext'+ i><br>"
    i++;
}
</script>
<body
<form name="form" action="post" method="">

    Titulo: <input type="text" name="t" + i> HERE I WANT THE NAME TO BE SOMETHING + THE i VARIABLE IN JAVASCRIPT
    <input type="button" value="test" onClick="changeIt()">
    <div id="my_div"></div>
    <br>

<input type="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to name the new dynamic textbox.
So I could call it later on another PHP page.

Comment: You can't use JS variables in PHP like that. JS is client side, PHP is server side. You should manually name the one in your script and dynamically name the others you add through JS.

Comment: Since I cant do JS + PHP, what is the solution ? How can I set different names for it.

Comment: I mean literally give the one in HTML the name `t1` and then dynamically name the others you add through JS starting from 2.

Comment: Sorry im a noob yet. So the code is ok its giving each textbox a name right ? Like mytext1... mytext2...

Comment: Well, no, because you didn't concatenate properly, `+ i` should be outside of quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send the javascript value through ajax POST to the server and read the post via php.

Not so sure what your aim is but let me know if this helps.

```html
<html>
<script language="javascript">
  var i = 1;

  function changeIt() {

    my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "Titulo: <input type='text' name='mytext'+ " + i + "><br>"
    i++;
  }
</script>

<body <form name="form" action="post" method="">

  Titulo: <input type="text" name="t" + i> HERE I WANT THE NAME TO BE SOMETHING + THE i VARIABLE IN JAVASCRIPT
  <input type="button" value="test" onClick="changeIt()">
  <div id="my_div"></div>
  <br>

  <input type="submit">

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```